# This Open Data site is 10 years old!

Tags: discussion

Can you believe it? :-)

Feel free to share any story about this site!

Rosie is going to be writing a Meta post for around June 15th acknowledging all of the sites that turn 10. There might also be a banner up on our site around that time to celebrate our anniversary.

Comment: Looking forward to celebrating this milestone with Open Data. Looking forward to hearing some stories about this community's first decade.

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a story or an anecdote to share, sorry.

After all these years, the site name is still "Open Data Beta" - Why is it still in Beta status?

I understand the traffic is a bit low, and some Qs are hard to answer.

Any plans to promote this site out of Beta status? (I don't mind if no such plans exist)

Comment: No plan that I am aware of. Would be nice, but I understand we still have to grow. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Open data site is transparent, easy to use website. It has less traffic, but many people have need of it, I think it have to grow to much. It can become social media of data sharing.